# Как запросить ввод чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо решить задачу о нахождении НОД для n чисел.
Решал я таким образом, вот код:

```
def find_gcd(x, y): 
    while(y): 
        x, y = y, x % y 
  
    return x       
      
l = [2, 4, 6, 8] 
num1=l[0] 
num2=l[1] 
gcd=find_gcd(num1,num2) 
  
for i in range(2,len(l)): 
    gcd=find_gcd(gcd,l[i]) 
      
print(gcd)
```

В данной программе вычисляется НОД чисел, введенные в списке l. Выводит 2 все правильно.
Теперь мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы числа вводились в самое программе, а не в коде. То есть чтобы появлялось поле "Введите числа ", я ввожу и мне выдается результат.
Пробовал сделать через

```
print('введите числа')
l = [int(elem) for elem in input().split()]
print(l)
```

Но почему-то выдается ошибка. Не подскажите в чем дело и как ее исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какая ошибка? Ничего криминального в строчке `l = [int(elem)...` нет. Может, во вводе мусор?

Comment: ` TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a0786abe391> in <module>
     22 
     23 for i in range(2,len(l)):
---> 24     gcd=find_gcd(gcd,l[i])
     25 
     26 print(gcd)

<ipython-input-1-5a0786abe391> in find_gcd(x, y)
      1 def find_gcd(x, y):
      2     while(y):
----> 3         x, y = y, x % y
      4 
      5     return x

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'function' and 'int' `

Comment: Покажите, что вводите. У меня работает для `1 2 3`

Comment: в заголовке нужно писать то, с чем у вас конкретная проблема, а не то, что делает ваша программа.

Answer (score 1):

Ввод списка чисел из input:

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом input:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

inputnumbers = input("Введите числа через запятую без пробелов: ")
numbarr = inputnumbers.split(",") #разобьем по запятой, получим массив
count = 0
while count < len(numbarr): # приобразуем все строки в массиве в числа
    numbarr[count] = int(numbarr[count])
    count += 1
print(reduce(gcd, numbarr))
```

Comment: мне нужно не только для двух чисел, а для n

Comment: @michail.kham, Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Числа в строке:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(gcd, map(int, input().split())))
```

Числа в столбик до первой пустой:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce
    
print(reduce(gcd, map(int, iter(input, ''))))
```

Comment: ну тут же числа вводятся в самом коде

Comment: @michail.kham не читал вопрос, исправил